# How to Flip & Rotate images on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, html5-canvas, electron

I'm building an Electron app which lays out images for batch printing on an industrial printer and I'm having an issue with images flipping / being mirrored.

Here is my code which determines whether an image should be flipped, rotated or both.

```
  _createClass(Image, null, [{
    key: 'drawRotatedImage',
    value: function drawRotatedImage(canvas, image, angle, mirrorImage) {
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (angle > 0) {
        context.rotate(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
      }
      if (mirrorImage === true) {
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(image, -image.width, -image.height, image.width, image.height);
      } else {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, angle === 0 ? 0 : -image.height);
      }
      return canvas;
    }
  },
```

The first part of the code recognises if an image needs to be rotated or not. This works fine. The 'mirrorImage' function however isn't working correctly for images that do not need to be rotated. Everything works perfectly on images that are rotated. Am I missing something? Can anybody help, this has been driving me mad for hours.

Thanks

Comment: It's a little bit unclear exactly what you want to achieve. I'm assuming you want your images to be flipped and/or rotated in place? But in your code, images are being rotated around the origin of the canvas, not the center of each image.

Comment: Update. I finally managed to fix it. I was lacking an IF to say that if an image is at 0 degrees (Landscape) AND Needs to be mirrored, then to just mirror image and not rotate. Code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value: function drawRotatedImage(canvas, image, angle, mirrorImage) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (angle > 0) {
        context.rotate(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
    }
    if (mirrorImage === true) {
        if (angle > 0) {
            context.scale(-1, 1);
            context.drawImage(image, -image.width, -image.height, image.width, image.height);
        }
    } 

    if (mirrorImage === true) {
        if (angle < 1) {
            context.scale(-1, 1);
            context.drawImage(image, -image.width, 0, image.width, image.height);
        }
    } else {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, angle === 0 ? 0 : -image.height);
    }
    return canvas;
}
```